# Python: is the iteration of the multidimensional array super slow?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have to iterate all items in two-dimensional array of integers and change the value (according to some rule, not important).

I'm surprised how significant difference in performance is there between python runtime and C# or java runtime. Did I wrote totally wrong python code (v2.7.2)?

```py
import numpy
a = numpy.ndarray((5000,5000), dtype = numpy.int32)
for x in numpy.nditer(a.T):
    x = 123
```

```sh
>python -m timeit -n 2 -r 2 -s "import numpy; a = numpy.ndarray((5000,5000), dtype=numpy.int32)" "for x in numpy.nditer(a.T):" "  x = 123"
2 loops, best of 2: 4.34 sec per loop
```

For example the C# code performs only 50ms, i.e. python is almost **100 times slower**! (suppose the `matrix` variable is already initialized)

```cs
for (y = 0; y < 5000; y++)
for (x = 0; x < 5000; x++)
    matrix[y][x] = 123;
```

Comment: Why are you surprised that an interpreted language is slower than a JIT compiled language?  Have you tried using [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) instead of CPython?

Comment: Using Numpy is all about avoiding explicit Python loops, and using vectorised NumPy functions instead.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: PyPy does not yet have NumPy support.

Comment: "according to some rule, not important": That rule *is* important if you want us to show you an efficient way to do it.

Comment: Am I missing something or is the Python example just assigning a local variable in a loop, while the second is modifying a matrix?! Also, what's the question here? How to make it faster?

Comment: @NiklasB.: That's of course true, but does not matter too much for the observed performance difference.  The code isn't meant to do something useful anyway.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: In my examples the rule is not important. Let's assign a constant value or do x+y, the difference in performance will be still the same.

Comment: @PetrFelzmann: but the performance difference with the proper vectorized Numpy idiom may be huge. Whether you wrote "totally wrong python code" depends on what you were trying to do.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes, the question is how to iterate through the array faster.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Thx, with PyPy and common python lists it performs ~500ms which is 10times better then CPython, but still 10times slower then .NET runtime.

Comment: @PetrFelzmann: PyPy lists are still very different from arrays.  The "correct" way to write such code in Python is vectorised NumPy code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is a much more dynamic language than C or C#.  The main reason why the loop is so slow is that on every pass, the CPython interpreter is doing some extra work that wastes time: specifically, it is binding the name `x` with the next object from the iterator, then when it evaluates the assignment it has to look up the name `x` again.

As @Sven Marnach noted, you can call a method function `numpy.fill()` and it is fast.  That function is compiled C or maybe Fortran, and it will simply loop over the addresses of the `numpy.array` data structure and fill in the values.  Much less dynamic than Python, which is good for this simple case.

But now consider PyPy.  Once you run your program under PyPy, a JIT analyzes what your code is actually doing.  In this example, it notes that the name `x` isn't used for anything but the assignment, and it can optimize away binding the name.  This example should be one that PyPy speeds up tremendously; likely PyPy will be ten times faster than plain Python (so only one-tenth as fast as C, rather than 1/100 as fast).

http://pypy.org

As I understand it, PyPy won't be working with Numpy for a while yet, so you can't just run your existing Numpy code under PyPy yet.  But the day is coming.

I'm excited about PyPy.  It offers the hope that we can write in a very high-level language (Python) and yet get nearly the performance of writing things in "portable assembly language" (C).  For examples like this one, the Numpy might even beat the performance of naive C code, by using SIMD instructions from the CPU (SSE2, NEON, or whatever).  For this example, with SIMD, you could set four integers to 123 with each loop, and that would be faster than a plain C loop.  (Unless the C compiler used a SIMD optimization also!  Which, come to think of it, is likely for this case.  So we are back to "nearly the speed of C" rather than faster for this example.  But we can imagine trickier cases that the C compiler isn't smart enough to optimize, where a future PyPy might.)

But never mind PyPy for now.  If you will be working with Numpy, it is a good idea to learn all the functions like `numpy.fill()` that are there to speed up your code.

Comment: Did the day come yet?

Comment: @Gulzar I haven't tested it, but recent releases of PyPy are able to run Numpy.  There is also NumPyPy, which is NumPy written in native PyPy.  http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#what-about-numpy-numpypy-micronumpy

Answer (score 13):

Yep!  Iterating through numpy arrays in python is slow.  (Slower than iterating through a python list, as well.)

Typically, you avoid iterating through them directly.

If you can give us an example of the rule you're changing things based on, there's a good chance that it's easy to vectorize.

As a toy example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 8*np.pi, 100)
y = np.cos(x)

x[y > 0] = 100
```

However, in many cases you have to iterate, either due to the algorithm (e.g. finite difference methods) or to lessen the memory cost of temporary arrays.

In that case, have a look at [Cython](http://cython.org/), [Weave](http://www.scipy.org/Weave/), or something similar.

Comment: please mention cpython in such posts. It's actually faster or not slower on pypy.

Comment: I did mention cpython (Or I was implying cpython with the numpy solution). Unless you're suggesting a pure python solution? (e.g. `from math import cos; y = [cos(item) for item in x]`) I'm confused...

Comment: well pypy has numpy support (to some extend) so the implied part is not valid.

Answer (score 10):

The example you gave was presumably meant to set all items of a two-dimensional NumPy array to 123.  This can be done efficiently like this:

```
a.fill(123)
```

or

```
a[:] = 123
```

Comment: And `numpy.fill` takes 50ms for the example 5000x5000 array, where the equivalent loop takes 3 seconds on the machine I am typing this on.....

Comment: @talonmies on my machine even 30ms ;)

Answer (score 4):

C++ emphasizes machine time over programmer time.

Python emphasizes programmer time over machine time.

Pypy is a python written in python, and they have the beginnings of numpy; you might try that.  Pypy has a nice JIT that makes things quite fast.

You could also try cython, which allows you to translate a dialect of Python to C, and compile the C to a Python C extension module; this allows one to continue using CPython for most of your code, while still getting a bit of a speedup.  However, in the one microbenchmark I've tried comparing Pypy and Cython, Pypy was quite a bit faster than Cython.

Cython uses a highly pythonish syntax, but it allows you to pretty freely intermix Python datatypes with C datatypes.  If you redo your hotspots with C datatypes, it should be pretty fast.  Continuing to use Python datatypes is sped up by Cython too, but not as much.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do operations on a multidimensional array that depend on the value of the array but don't depend on the position inside the array then `.itemset` is 5 times faster than `nditer` for me.

So instead of doing something like

```
image = np.random.random_sample((200, 200,3));
with np.nditer(image, op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
    for x in it:
        x[...] = x*4.5 if x<0.2 else x
```

You can do this

```
image2 = np.random.random_sample((200, 200,3));
for i in range(0,image2.size):
    x = image2.item(i)
    image2.itemset(i, x*4.5 if x<0.2 else x);
```

Comment: +1 - Wanted to mention: with those requirements, people should consider trying to avoid the Python loop altogether. Your specific example can be written as: `mask = image2 < 0.2` to create a mask, and then `image2[mask] = (image2 * 4.5)[mask]` to set the values. On my machine, using `itemset()` with a loop runs in 29ms and using masks runs in 95µs giving >300x speedup.

Answer (score 0):

The `nditer` code does not assign a value to the elements of `a`.  This doesn't affect the timings issue, but I mention it because it should not be taken as a good use of `nditer`.

a correct version is:

```
for i in np.nditer(a, op_flags=[["readwrite"]]):
    i[...] = 123
```

The `[...]` is needed to retain the reference to loop value, which is an array of shape `()`.

There's no point in using `A.T`, since its the values of the base `A` that get changed.

I agree that the proper way of doing this assignment is `a[:]=123`.