# Numpy: Beginner nditer

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

I am trying to learn [nditer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.nditer.html) for possible use in speeding up my application. Here, i try to make a facetious reshape program that will take a size 20 array and reshape it to a 5x4 array:

```
myArray = np.arange(20)
def fi_by_fo_100(array):
    offset = np.array([0, 4, 8, 12, 16])
    it = np.nditer([offset, None],
                      flags=['reduce_ok'],
                      op_flags=[['readonly'],
                                ['readwrite','allocate']],
                      op_axes=[None, [0,1,-1]],
                      itershape=(-1, 4, offset.size))

    while not it.finished:
        indices = np.arange(it[0],(it[0]+4), dtype=int)
        info = array.take(indices)
        '''Just for fun, we'll perform an operation on data.\
           Let's shift it to 100'''
        info = info + 81
        it.operands[1][...]=info
        it.iternext()
    return it.operands[1]

test = fi_by_fo_100(myArray)
>>> test
array([[ 97,  98,  99, 100]])
```

Clearly the program is overwriting each result into one row. So i try using the indexing functionality of nditer, but still no dice.

`flags=['reduce_ok','c_iter']` --> `it.operands[1][it.index][...]=info` =
 `IndexError: index out of bounds`

`flags=['reduce_ok','c_iter']` --> `it.operands[1][it.iterindex][...]=info` =
 `IndexError: index out of bounds`

`flags=['reduce_ok','multi_iter']` --> `it.operands[1][it.multi_index][...]=info` =
 `IndexError: index out of bounds`

`it[0][it.multi_index[1]][...]=info` = 
`IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed`

...and so on. What am i missing? Thanks in advance.

### Bonus Question

I just happened across [this nice article on nditer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112745/python-is-the-iteration-of-the-multidimensional-array-super-slow). I may be new to Numpy, but this is the first time i've seen Numpy speed benchmarks this far behind. It's my understanding that people choose Numpy for it's numerical speed and prowess, but iteration is a part of that, no? What is the point of nditer if it's so slow?

Comment: Keep in mind that the whole point of `numpy` is _avoiding_ iteration, and doing everything through vectorized operations. While `nditer` is designed to be the most efficient way to iterate over a `numpy` array, you're still doing Python loops instead of vector operations, so a slowdown—often a very large one—is pretty much unavoidable. The article you linked explains this in detail (although it's a bit out of date as far as PyPy… support isn't 100% complete, but `import numpypy; import numpy as np` is definitely good enough for playing around with).

Comment: Also, I assume you already know this, and are more interested here in learning `nditer` than finding the fastest way to do this, but just in case: `def fi_by_fo_100(array): return array.reshape(5, 4) + 81`.

Comment: @abarnert I didn't really understand everything that they were saying in that article, but thanks for the summary. Yes, i am aware of `reshape`. This is just a little tutorial-thing for my edification.

But back to the subject of speed, when you say "vectorized operations", do you mean [numpy.vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)? Are you implying that my effort would be better spent learning numpy.vectorize?

Comment: No, I mean doing element-wise operations in `numpy`, as with `info = info + 81` instead of `for x in range(info.size): info[x] = info[x] + 81`. Whenever it's possible to write something the former way, it will be much, much faster.

Comment: Meanwhile, your problem here is that `it.operands[1]` is the entire output iteration, and you're reassigning the whole thing each time through the loop. You want to just assign a single row. However, I can see that you already tried to find ways to do that, so I'm guessing you already figured that out. Are you interested in why your attempts don't work, or what would work?

Comment: @abarnert Both, i suppose...I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: I was delayed by dinner and various other things, but I think I covered everything I was hoping to… whether that answers all of your questions or not, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It really helps to break things down by printing out what's going on along the way.

First, let's replace your whole loop with this:

```
i = 0
while not it.finished:
    i += 1
print i
```

It'll print 20, not 5. That's because you're doing a 5x4 iteration, not 5x1.

So, why is this even close to working? Well, let's look at the loop more carefully:

```
while not it.finished:
    print '>', it.operands[0], it[0]
    indices = np.arange(it[0],(it[0]+4), dtype=int)
    info = array.take(indices)
    info = info + 81
    it.operands[1][...]=info
    print '<', it.operands[1], it[1]
```

You'll see that the first five loops go through `[0 4 8 12 16]` five times, generating `[[81 82 83 84]]`, then `[[85 86 87 88]]`, etc. And then the next five loops do the same thing, and again and again.

This is also why your `c_index` solutions didn't work—because `it.index` is going to range from 0 to 19, and you don't have 20 of anything in `it.operands[1]`.

If you did the multi_index right and ignored the columns, you could make this work… but still, you'd be doing a 5x4 iteration, just to repeat each step 4 times, instead of doing the 5x1 iteration you want.

Your `it.operands[1][...]=info` replaces the entire output with a 5x1 row each time through the loop. Generally, you shouldn't ever have to do anything to `it.operands[1]`—the whole point of `nditer` is that you just take care of each `it[1]`, and the final `it.operands[1]` is the result.

Of course a 5x4 iteration over rows makes no sense. Either do a 5x4 iteration over individual values, or a 5x1 iteration over rows.

If you want the former, the easiest way to do it is to reshape the input array, then just iterate that:

```
it = np.nditer([array.reshape(5, -1), None],
               op_flags=[['readonly'],
                         ['readwrite','allocate']])
for a, b in it:
    b[...] = a + 81
return it.operands[1]
```

But of course that's silly—it's just a slower and more complicated way of writing:

```
return array+81
```

And it would be a bit silly to suggest that "the way to write your own `reshape` is to first call `reshape`, and then…"

So, you want to iterate over rows, right?

Let's simplify things a bit by getting rid of the `allocate` and explicitly creating a 5x4 array to start with:

```
outarray = np.zeros((5,4), dtype=array.dtype)
offset = np.array([0, 4, 8, 12, 16])
it = np.nditer([offset, outarray],
               flags=['reduce_ok'],
               op_flags=[['readonly'],
                         ['readwrite']],
               op_axes=[None, [0]],
               itershape=[5])

while not it.finished:
    indices = np.arange(it[0],(it[0]+4), dtype=int)
    info = array.take(indices)
    '''Just for fun, we'll perform an operation on data.\
       Let's shift it to 100'''
    info = info + 81
    it.operands[1][it.index][...]=info
    it.iternext()
return it.operands[1]
```

This is a bit of an abuse of `nditer`, but at least it does the right thing.

Since you're just doing a 1D iteration over the source and basically ignoring the second, there's really no good reason to use `nditer` here. If you need to do lockstep iteration over multiple arrays, `for a, b in nditer([x, y], …)` is cleaner than iterating over `x` and using the index to access `y`—just like `for a, b in zip(x, y)` outside of `numpy`. And if you need to iterate over multi-dimensional arrays, `nditer` is usually cleaner than the alternatives. But here, all you're really doing is iterating over `[0, 4, 8, 16, 20]`, doing something with the result, and copying it into another `array`.

Also, as I mentioned in the comments, if you find yourself using iteration in `numpy`, you're usually doing something wrong. All of the speed benefits of `numpy` come from letting it execute the tight loops in native C/Fortran or lower-level vector operations. Once you're looping over `array`s, you're effectively just doing slow Python numerics with a slightly nicer syntax:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def add10_numpy(array):
    return array + 10

def add10_nditer(array):
    it = np.nditer([array, None], [],
                   [['readonly'], ['writeonly', 'allocate']])
    for a, b in it:
        np.add(a, 10, b)
    return it.operands[1]

def add10_py(array):
    x, y = array.shape
    outarray = array.copy()
    for i in xrange(x):
        for j in xrange(y):
            outarray[i, j] = array[i, j] + 10
    return out array

myArray = np.arange(100000).reshape(250,-1)

for f in add10_numpy, add10_nditer, add10_py:
    print '%12s: %s' % (f.__name__, timeit.timeit(lambda: f(myArray), number=1))
```

On my system, this prints:

```
 add10_numpy: 0.000458002090454
add10_nditer: 0.292730093002
    add10_py: 0.127345085144
```

That shows you the cost of using `nditer` unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you very much, @abarnert. This is more than enough to get me going. Very informative.