# Whats the best way to iterate over multidimensional array and tracking/doing operations on iteration index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I need to do a lot of operations on multidimensional numpy arrays and therefor i am experimenting towards the best approach on this.

So let's say i have an array like this:

```
A = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size = 100).reshape(20, 5)
```

My goal is to get the maximum value `numpy.amax()` of each entry and it's index. So may `A[0]` be something like this:

`A[0] = [ 0.64570441  0.31781716  0.07268926  0.84183753  0.72194227]`

I want to get the maximum and the index of that maximum `[0.84183753][0, 3]`. No specific representation of the results needed, just an example. I even need the horizontal index only.

I tried using numpy's nditer object:

```
A_it = np.nditer(A, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite'])

while not A_it.finished:
    print(np.amax(A_it.value))
    print(A_it.multi_index[1])
    A_it.iternext()
```

I can access every element of the array and its index over the iterations that way but i don't seem to be able to bring the `numpy.amax()` function in each element and the index together syntax wise. Can i even do it using `nditer`object?

Also, in [Numpy: Beginner nditer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188807/numpy-beginner-nditer) i read that using `nditer` or using iterations in numpy usually means that i am doing something wrong. But i can't find another convenient way to achieve my goal here without any iterations. Obviously i am a total beginner in numpy and python in general, so any keyword to search for or hint is very much appreciated.

Comment: A.argmax(axis=1) ?

Comment: Don't use `nditer`.  Use regular python for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A major problem with `nditer` is that it iterates over each element, not each row.  It's best used as a stepping stone toward a Cython or C rewrite of your code.

If you just want the maximum for each row of your array, a simple iteration or list comprehension will do nicely.

```
for row in A: print(np.amax(row))
```

or to turn it back into an array:

```
np.array([np.amax(row) for row in A])
```

But you can get the same values by giving `amax` an axis parameter

```
np.amax(A,axis=1)
```

`np.argmax` identifies the location of the maximum.

```
np.argmax(A,axis=1)
```

With the argmax values you could then select the max values as well,

```
ind=np.argmax(A,axis=1)
A[np.arange(A.shape[0]),ind]
```

(speed's about the same as repeating the `np.amax` call).