# Python How to replace values in specific columns (defined by an array) with zero

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to replace values in specific columns with zero with python, and the column numbers are specified in another array.

Given the following 2 numpy arrays

```
a = np.array([[  1,   2,   3,   4],
              [  1,   2,   1,   2],
              [  0,   3,   2,   2]])
```

and

```
b = np.array([1,3])
```

b indicates column numbers in array "a" where values need to be replaced with zero.
So the expected output is

```
            ([[  1,   0,   3,   0],
              [  1,   0,   1,   0],
              [  0,   0,   2,   0]])
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Try this `a[:, 1::2] = 0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace one column by a value in a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952946/how-to-replace-one-column-by-a-value-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is:

> I'm trying to replace values in specific columns with zero with python, and the column numbers are specified in another array.

This can be done like this:

```py
a[:,b] = 0
```

Output:

```
[[1 0 3 0]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 2 0]]
```

The [Integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) section of [Indexing on ndarrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) in the numpy docs has some similar examples.

Comment: Do you need additional help with your question?

Answer (score 1):

A simple for loop will accomplish this.

```py
for column in b:
    for row in range(len(a)):
        a[row][column] = 0
        
print(a)
```

```
[[1 0 3 0]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 2 0]]
```

Comment: iterating over a numpy array sort of defeats the point of using one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112745/python-is-the-iteration-of-the-multidimensional-array-super-slow